# Product of orthogonal projection operators onto range R$(X)$ and R(X')

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, orthogonality

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{T \times N}$. I am interested in investigating the term $X(X'X)^{-1}X'=(XX^+)(X'^+X')$ where $(\cdot)^+$ denotes the [Moore-Penrose-Pseudoinverse.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) According to [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Projectors) these two terms are  orthogonal projection operators:
$$P:=XX^+ \text{ is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $X$}\\
Q:=X'^+X' \text{ is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $X'$}\\
$$
Therefore the term I am interested in is the product of two projection matrices $P$ and $Q$ with R($X)$ and R($X')$. Are there any commonly known properties of such a form?

Comment: First of all, if $(X'X)^{-1}$ makes sense then $X(X'X)^{-1}X'=XX^+$.

Comment: Thank you @AlgebraicPavel, I did not see that although it follows immediately from the properties of the pseudoinverse. Therefore this problem does not depend on investigating the product of orthogonal projections anymore. But just out of curiosity: This also implies that $PQ=P$? Is there an intuitive way to explain this regardless of the representation with the pseudoinverse?

Comment: Note that the projection onto the range of $X'$ is actually $Q=X'X'^+=(X^+X)'=X^+X$. Generally $PQ\neq P$.